AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'version'
OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
CUDA: 11.3
GPU: NVIDIA P5000 Quadro
IDE: Jupyter Notebook
Environment: VirtualEnv (venv)

Code:
# Importing the required libraries
import torch

from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, BitsAndBytesConfig

# Defining the name of the Falcon model
model_name = "ybelkada/falcon-7b-sharded-bf16"

# Configuring the BitsAndBytes quantization
bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
load_in_4bit=True,
bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.float16,
)

# Loading the Falcon model with quantization configuration
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
model_name,
quantization_config=bnb_config,
trust_remote_code=True
)

# Disabling cache usage in the model configuration
model.config.use_cache = False

Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/FYP_Chatbot/test02/src/myenv-test002-02/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py:242, in _lazy_init()
    241 try:
--> 242     queued_call()
    243 except Exception as e:

File ~/FYP_Chatbot/test02/src/myenv-test002-02/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py:122, in _check_capability()
    116 old_gpu_warn = """
    117 Found GPU%d %s which is of cuda capability %d.%d.
    118 PyTorch no longer supports this GPU because it is too old.
    119 The minimum cuda capability supported by this library is %d.%d.
    120 """
--> 122 if torch.version.cuda is not None:  # on ROCm we don't want this check
    123     CUDA_VERSION = torch._C._cuda_getCompiledVersion()

AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'version'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

DeferredCudaCallError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 17
     10 bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
     11 load_in_4bit=True,
     12 bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
     13 bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.float16,
     14 )
     16 # Loading the Falcon model with quantization configuration
---> 17 model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
     18 model_name,
     19 quantization_config=bnb_config,
     20 trust_remote_code=True
     21 )
     23 # Disabling cache usage in the model configuration
     24 model.config.use_cache = False

File ~/FYP_Chatbot/test02/src/myenv-test002-02/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/auto_factory.py:563, in _BaseAutoModelClass.from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
    561 elif type(config) in cls._model_mapping.keys():
    562     model_class = _get_model_class(config, cls._model_mapping)
--> 563     return model_class.from_pretrained(
    564         pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, config=config, **hub_kwargs, **kwargs
    565     )
    566 raise ValueError(
    567     f"Unrecognized configuration class {config.__class__} for this kind of AutoModel: {cls.__name__}.\n"
    568     f"Model type should be one of {', '.join(c.__name__ for c in cls._model_mapping.keys())}."
    569 )

File ~/FYP_Chatbot/test02/src/myenv-test002-02/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py:3053, in PreTrainedModel.from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, config, cache_dir, ignore_mismatched_sizes, force_download, local_files_only, token, revision, use_safetensors, *model_args, **kwargs)
   3049 hf_quantizer.validate_environment(
   3050     torch_dtype=torch_dtype, from_tf=from_tf, from_flax=from_flax, device_map=device_map
   3051 )
   3052 torch_dtype = hf_quantizer.update_torch_dtype(torch_dtype)
-> 3053 device_map = hf_quantizer.update_device_map(device_map)
   3055 # Force-set to `True` for more mem efficiency
   3056 if low_cpu_mem_usage is None:

File ~/FYP_Chatbot/test02/src/myenv-test002-02/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/quantizers/quantizer_bnb_4bit.py:246, in Bnb4BitHfQuantizer.update_device_map(self, device_map)
    244 def update_device_map(self, device_map):
    245     if device_map is None:
--> 246         device_map = {"": torch.cuda.current_device()}
    247         logger.info(
    248             "The device_map was not initialized. "
    249             "Setting device_map to {'':torch.cuda.current_device()}. "
    250             "If you want to use the model for inference, please set device_map ='auto' "
    251         )
    252     return device_map

File ~/FYP_Chatbot/test02/src/myenv-test002-02/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py:552, in current_device()
    550 def current_device() -> int:
    551     r"""Returns the index of a currently selected device."""
--> 552     _lazy_init()
    553     return torch._C._cuda_getDevice()

File ~/FYP_Chatbot/test02/src/myenv-test002-02/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py:246, in _lazy_init()
    243         except Exception as e:
    244             msg = (f"CUDA call failed lazily at initialization with error: {str(e)}\n\n"
    245                    f"CUDA call was originally invoked at:\n\n{orig_traceback}")
--> 246             raise DeferredCudaCallError(msg) from e
    247 finally:
    248     delattr(_tls, 'is_initializing')

DeferredCudaCallError: CUDA call failed lazily at initialization with error: module 'torch' has no attribute 'version'

Environment Packages:
accelerate==0.29.1 
bitsandbytes==0.43.0 
datasets==2.18.0 
einops==0.7.0 
fsspec==2023.10.0 
peft @ git+https://github.com/huggingface/peft.git@26726bf1ddee6ca75ed4e1bfd292094526707a78 torch==1.13.0 transformers==4.39.3 
trl==0.8.1 
wandb==0.16.6

I encountered the error after downgrading PyTorch 2.2.2 to PyTorch 1.13.0. I had to downgrade PyTorch 2.2.2 because of the fact that I have cuda toolkit of version 11.3 which was not compatible with the later versions of PyTorch. I downgraded PyTorch to version 1.13.0 specifically because I am using "transformers" library from huggingface which requires PyTorch version >= 1.13.0.
Nvidia Graphics Cards Details (nvidia-smi):
Sat Apr  6 22:40:45 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.182.03   Driver Version: 470.182.03   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P5000        Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  Off |
| 27%   44C    P8     6W / 180W |    295MiB / 16275MiB |      3%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A       938      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                103MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1150      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               37MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1986      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox          150MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

nvcc -V:
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Mar_21_19:15:46_PDT_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.3, V11.3.58
Build cuda_11.3.r11.3/compiler.29745058_0


Did you reinstall the transformers library after the downgrade?

Yes I did reinstalled the transformers library after the downgrade, without explicitly uninstalling the transformers library.

I suggest you try explicitly uninstalling

can you show your nvidia-smi output?

@Ivan I have added outputs of nvidia-smi and nvcc -V in the above body of question.

@YakovDan I have explicitly uninstalled every library and reinstalled each of them after installing PyTorch 1.13.0. Despite that the error persists.

According to the information given in your post, you have two requirements:

the transformers package you are trying to use requires a PyTorch version of >= 1.13.0

the maximum CUDA version supported by your GPU is 11.4, so the CUDA toolkit  installed via PyTorch must be <= 11.4


That CUDA version was decommissioned on the release of PyTorch 1.13, see release notes. So a viable solution for you would be to see whether you can update your CUDA driver to 11.6 or 11.7. With that version, you will be able to install PyTorch 1.13 with the appropriate CUDA toolkit.

How about me downgrading CUDA? Because I was able to run the above code without any errors while I had CUDA version 9. I had to reinstall my operating system for some reason, and I decided to install CUDA version 11.3 on that operating system.

Which version of PyTorch did you have back then? Are you referring to the CUDA toolkit provided with PyTorch?

PyTorch version 1.13.0. I do not remember the exact CUDA version but it was version 9 point something for sure.

I don't see how this would work because anything lower than 11.6 is not compatible with 1.13 according to the release not I linked. Are you sure you indeed had access to the GPU with PyTorch at that point?

Yes I am 100 % sure. I had finetuned falcon-7b using the same hardware specs. Yes I had access to GPU and PyTorch. Used this same PC for the fine tuning. I am also confused as to why things are not working out. But I just recalled that when I ran the said code, when I had CUDA version 9, I was getting some warning of some sort. But that did not result in an error. So everything was working.

I don't know then, if you look here, you will see only torch-1.13.0+cu116 and torch-1.13.0+cu117 are available, nothing lower. Did you happen to compile the pytorch library with a lower CUDA version? Also, an important question regarding "I had CUDA version 9", where did you get access to that version number?

Update: Thank you for helping out Ivan, I think it was due to someone else using the same PC and meddling with CUDA, that's why. But anyways I updated my CUDA to version 12.1 and it worked. Forgot to get back here. Anyways, thanks a ton for helping out.

Use something likes this
Set up (you can ignore, I am using JupyterLab)
!python --version

!pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121

import torch

m1 = torch.Tensor([1, 2, 3])
m2 = torch.Tensor([4, 5, 6])
m3 = m1.add(m2)
print(m3)

import torch
print(torch.__version__)

result
2.1.2+cu121


If OP is limited by CUDA version 11.3, then installing PyTorch compiled on CUDA 12.1 won't work.
